# Transparent video strip over background image

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have a video that I shot myself in front of a solid gray colored wall. Now what I want to do is, place an image in the back and put the video of myself in front and make the gray areas in the video transparent so the background image shows behind me.

I tried putting the assets in to the sequencer and added Effect Strips and played with the Alpha Over / Under settings to no avail.

Is Blender enough for this or am I going around in circles?

Comment: What you are trying to do is a luma key. Do a search for that.

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI1kMT3O6uk